# @material-ui/Icons error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use the @material-ui/Icons component in my React project but when I try to include the imported icon into my code I receive the following error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare, displayName, muiName}).
```

Which is fairly standard for when you try to display an Object rather than one of its values. However in this case I'm not entirely sure how to display the icon I imported.

I tried console.logging the icon to see if I could make any sense of what was going wrong, but it didn't help.

I've also tried importing:

```
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core';
```

But it still didn't work.

I import my icon:

```
import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';
```

Then I try to insert it into my page (simplified example}:

```
<Fragment>
   {AccessAlarmIcon}
</Fragment>
```

As far as I understand it this should just show the Icon, instead I just get the error

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare, displayName, muiName}).
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Should I be importing something else from `@material-ui/core`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are not referencing it as a React class. It should be a tag to be used.
You can define you Icon like below. I've tried it and it worked:

```
<Fragment>
     <AccessAlarm/>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: I got confused between the two, very sorry! Thank you for the quick answer

Comment: That's ok. I just checked the documentation and tried it myself and it worked.